# Why is there a space in front of the variable I define with url query?

Tags: php

```
echo '<form style="text-align:center;" action="redirect.php" method="post">';
echo '<input  type="hidden" name="user" value=" ';
echo $row['fromuser'] ;
echo ' ">';
```

This code sends the variable `$row['fromuser']` to a redirect page. When the redirect page gets it, the code looks like this.

```
session_start();
$user=$_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['person']=$user;
header ("Location:message.php?user={$user}") ?>
```

However, the `redirect.php` redirects to `message.php?user=%20johnsmith` instead of `message.php?user=johnsmith`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .... seriously?

Answer (score 4):

```
echo '<input  type="hidden" name="user" value=" ';
//                                             ^
```

There's your space.

Simply remove it:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="user" value="';
```

---

You have another one here:

```
echo ' ">';
//    ^
```